# What is the purpose of the % in the following code?

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I am making a snake game for my university assignment. In C. Now, I know this isn't the ideal langiage for the task but it's my assignment. I found an example code anda am currently rewriting it / understanding it so I can write my own working code. So far it's an easy ride and it's all coming together but for the life of me I can't figure out why they put a the % in the following lines:

```
        for (i = 1; i <= 1 + rand() % 10; i++)
            food.x = 12 + rand() % (68 - 12);
        for (i = 1; i <= 1 + rand() % 10; i++)
            food.y = 12 + rand() % (28 - 12);
```

For context this is in the function for creating food in the playing field. I understand the rand thing and adding these numbers (it's my playing field size) but why put a modulo division? What does it achieve?

Comment: `rand()` generates a number between 0 and RAND_MAX.  `rand() % 10` generates a number between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is the modulo operator, mostly used like in this scenario to limit a value see [modulo operator wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

f.e.
`1 + rand() % 10` means the value will be 1 + [0..9] - so max is 10. [0..9] is the random number modulo 10, and will be a number between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

% is the "modulo" operator , i.e.: it's the remainder of the integer division of its two operands.

That's one way to guarantee the output of rand() is within a certain range.
e.g.: **rand()%100** will be between **0** and **99**

In other words: **12 + rand() % (68 - 12)** will be between 12 and 67

Because: **rand()%(68-12)** is between **0** and **68-12-1**

And so: **12+rand()%(68-12)** is between **12** and **67**